# how to find all near words in string in c# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

```
Regex.Matches("word1 word1 word1", @"\bword1\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,1}?word1\b");
```

this Regex return only one occurrence `"word1 word1"`

What i need to add to this Regex to get all occurrences as below (may be some recursive pattern)?

1. `"word1 word1"`
2. `"word1 word1"`
3. `"word1 word1 word1"`

Sorry my (confusing) example is not a question about repeated words. To be more clear i give a second example : "xxx_w1 aa yyy_w1 zzz_w1".
I want to get the words ending by "_w1" separated by space ore one word (some distance) and the result for my example should be :

1. xxx_w1 aa yyy_w1
2. yyy_w1 zzz_w1

The issue with my Regex above is that i get only the first match instead of the two maches above.

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Shouldn't you only want the `word1` X 3. Why the other two times

Comment: I think this has been asked several times before. I'm not really sure what you really want but let's throw some guesses: `(\w+)(?:\s+\1)*`, `(\w+)(?:\s+\1)+`, `\bword1\b(?: \bword1\b)*`, `\bword1\b(?: \bword1\b)+`.

Comment: I update my question to give more details, it's not about repeated words, so your regex don't give the expected result

Answer (score 0):

To find repeated words in a text, try this pattern:

```
\b(\w+)\b(?:\s*\1)+
```

And here it is in action:

[image: Finding repeated words in a string]

Comment: I update my question to give more details, your Regex give also just "one" match insetead of expected 3 matches